# How can I put a Windows7 shared folder on my ubuntu desktop?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, shared-folders

I've got a network with several machines running Ubuntu 12.04 and one server running Windows7. The server has many shared folders. I've managed to connect to those folders and add them inside nautilus as bookmarks, so they mount whenever I click on them, which is fine. Now I'd like to add those same folder on the desktop, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no "easy" way to do this (easy= drag and drop kind of solution), but here is a reasonable solution for unprotected (guest) network folders.

Install CFIS

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Create the mount directory. You will need a separate directory for each mount.

```
sudo mkdir /media/windowsshare
```

Then edit your /etc/fstab file (with root privileges) to add this line:

```
//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

Where "guest" indicates you don't need a password to access the share, "uid=1000" makes the Linux user specified by the id the owner of the mounted share, allowing them to rename files, "iocharset=utf8" allows access to files with names in non-English languages.

After you add the entry to /etc/fstab type:

```
sudo mount -a
```

This will (re)mount all entries listed in /etc/fstab.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Nautilus as root: $ sudo nautilus and then just copy folders to your desktop.

Cheers,

Luis

Comment: It's odd, I can't even connect to any share when I open nautilus with sudo. The system asks me to check gvfs, but I have it installed.